# WordPress REST API - hide field for non logged users

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

With [this example](https://bay-a.co.uk/wordpress-tips/wp-api-v2-tips/) I manage to add custom post type and custom meta data in WordPress REST API.

Right now I'm trying to hide some of the data for non logged users and I'm trying like this:

```
    add_filter( 'rest_prepare_the_event', 'add_meta_to_json', 10, 3 );
    function add_meta_to_json($data, $post, $request){

    $response_data = $data->get_data();

    if ( $request['context'] !== 'view' || is_wp_error( $data ) ) {
        return $data;
    }


    $start = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_the_event_start', true );
    if(empty($start)){
        $start = '';
    }

    $end = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_the_event_end', true );
    if(empty($end)){
        $end = '';
    }

    $location = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_the_event_location', true );
    if(empty($location)){
        $location = '';
    }

    if($post->post_type == 'the_event'){
        $response_data['event_meta'] = array(
            'start' => $start,
            'end' => $end,
            'location' => $location,
        );

        if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
            unset($response_data['event_meta']['location']);
        }   
    }

    $data->set_data( $response_data );

    return $data;
    }
```

In above example code I'm trying to hide *location* field to non logged users but this is not working.
How to hide that field for non logged users?

Answer (score 0):

I see your code fine... but you can to try:

```
if($post->post_type == 'the_event'){
    $response_data['event_meta'] = array(
        'start' => $start,
        'end' => $end
    );

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $response_data['event_meta']['location'] = $location;
    }   
}
```